# How to create Twitter like profile layout?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create Twitter like profile layout in React Native. Although many apps use this pattern. My current JSX setup is something like this.

- Header (profile)
- ViewPagerNav (custom)
- ViewPager

  - Tab with ListView
  - Tab with ListView

Problem is that only bottom part scrolls. I have seen this problem for many React Native apps. Is there a solution for this?

How should my render view look like to g full get page scrolling?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a really good example of this in the [F8 app](http://makeitopen.com/). The 3 files you want to look at are here:

https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/tabs/schedule/MyScheduleView.js
https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/ListContainer.js
https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/PureListView.js

If you want to see how it works in the app it is the My F8 tab.

The basic idea is that the `ListContainer` keeps track of the scroll position via the [`handleScroll`](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/ListContainer.js#L257) function. It passes `handleScroll` to all of its [children](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/ListContainer.js#L159) renaming the function to `onScroll`.

The `PureListView` a it takes that `onScroll` property via the object spread operator [`{...this.props}`](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/PureListView.js#L103) and passes it into the `ListView`.

That is all just to keep track of the scroll. If you look in [`MyScheduleView.js`](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/tabs/schedule/MyScheduleView.js#L94) you can see how it is mostly implemented.

Comment: At first, I looked at "My F8" screen for a while and thought you misunderstood my question. There is no such behavior on my android device. But from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeSHQUto-nU) I can tell that there is something different going on on iOS. Seem to me that this only works for iOS and not android devices. Someone got lazy at FB? I will dig deeper and try to understand how exactly it works.

Comment: I don't think this answer is still relevant? As `onScroll` has been commented out? https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/2fb0a87cb3854a9340a679cbdf36d02975e9b6c3/js/common/ListContainer.js#L98