# React Native profile layout similar to Twitter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, twitter, tabs, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement a profile layout similar to twitter's but I'm having trouble getting sufficient guides on how to accomplish such a task in react native. My approach is having some of the user details in the header and have the header components animate as the user scrolls. similar to Twitter. The profile layout should also have multiple tabs.

The closest I've come into solving this issue is by using, [react-native-collapsible](https://github.com/benevbright/react-navigation-collapsible) which allows for easy implementations of animated headers. However, I faced two major issues when trying this approach. The header is only rendered once. I tried solving this by resetting the header using `navigation.setOptions()`. This approach didn't work as the header didn't animate.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581213/5895888) which may be outdated as the demo app seems to not be available.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Googling 'react native tab view animated header' will give some solutions on how it can be done. [this](https://medium.com/@linjunghsuan/implementing-a-collapsible-header-with-react-native-tab-view-24f15a685e07) worked for me. The linked repository proved to be helpful.

Comment: Hi, have you tried [react-native-collapsible-tab-view](https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view)? PS: I'm the author. I can elaborate on a better answer if you want.